# Get parent node in android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my current code. How can I get the parent node of the first name

[image: my Firebase DB]

```
final Query userQuery = mRef.orderByChild("First Name");

    userQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            map.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                String key = child.getKey().toString();
                String value = child.getValue().toString();
                map.put(key,value);
            }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should call the `getKey()` method in your retrieved `dataSnapshot`:

```
  final Query userQuery = mRef.orderByChild("First Name");

  userQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        map.clear();
        //Get the node from the datasnapshot
        String myParentNode = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
           String key = child.getKey().toString();
           String value = child.getValue().toString();
           map.put(key,value);
        }
```

Comment: String myParentNode = dataSnapshot.getKey() actually returns "Users". I'm still confused. :(

Comment: if your `dataSnapshot.getKey() ` returns you `Users` then `child.getKey()` should return you "asdfasdfa"

Comment: Has anyone found the solution to this?