# Firebase retrieve parent data using child data in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get the parent by using its child user ID? Since I get the userID only when user is log in. I want to list out all their food using their user ID.

[image]

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/41808580/4168607.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use orderByChild and equalTo to get food object snapshot, after that get key of foodSnapshot

```
final Query userQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Food").orderByChild("uid");

    userQuery.equalTo("BNeBA...........").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot foodSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    // result
                    String key = foodSnapshot.getKey();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        }
    );
```

ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Answer (score 1):

this is the code that work for me.

```
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    ref.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("u_username").getValue();
            show_username.setText(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Those keys are created by the `push()` method, you should get this keys after you get your datasnapshot with `getKey()`.

After your `datasnapshot.getChildren()` is called, you should make an string:

```
String myParentKey = datasnapshot.getKey().toString();
```

in order to get the parent key of all your children. This is inside a loop of course, here is a hint:

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String myParentKey = childSnapshot.getKey().toString();
            ....
```

Comment: sorry i'm beginner for firebase.. is that means after i inserted a new food then i need to get the key immediately? if one user insert many foods?

Comment: When the for loop statement you will be getting all the new keys generated by the new values , you just will need to declare one time the getkey